# Not existance of one sided limit

Tags: real-analysis, functions, convergence-divergence

I have a question regarding one sided limits of functions. Let's say that the function $f$ is defined in $(a,b)$. And let's say that we want to check the limit of $f$ when it approaches b from the left. I know that one situation for the limit not to exist is when we can find at least 2 sequences $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ which converge to b from the left,  such that $f(x_n)\rightarrow L$ and $f(y_n)\rightarrow L'$ and $L$ would be different from $L'$. My question is, will this be the only case where a one sided limit would not exist? Or are there other cases as well? (Note: Of course I consider convergence to infinity as existence of a limit, so you can exclude this as a case). Your help is much appreciated, thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

The only other example I can think of off the top of my head is called "erratic behaviour." For example, take the function

$f(x)=\sin \dfrac{1}{x}$. It is continuous at pretty much every real value, but the limit as it approaches 0 (from the right or the left) is undefined.